# Can’t send array from store module through parent element to child element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a store module :

```
const state = {
    todoList: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Todo One"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Todo Two"
        }
    ]
};

const getters = {
    getTodoList: (state) => state.todoList
};

const actions = {

};
const mutations = {

};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

I have a parent element:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <h2>Todo List</h2>
    <Todo />
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="enterTodo"
        placeholder="What are you up today ?"

      />
      <button type="submit"
        @click="addTask"
      ><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import Todo from "./Todo.vue";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "TodoContainer",
  components: {
    Todo,
  },
  props: [],
  methods: {
    addTask: () => {

    }
  },  
  computed: mapGetters(["getTodoList"]),
};
</script>
```

and I have the child element:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="todo" v-for="todo in getTodoList" :key="todo.id">
      {{ todo.title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Todo",
  props: ["getTodoList"],
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

The problem is that `getTodoList` is `undefined` in the child element.
**How can I send the `todoList` from the store module through the parent element to the child element ?**
There are no real tutorials, the guidelines are lacking and I haven't found anything remotely similar to my particular case.

Comment: Does this help: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props?

Comment: I have written `props: ["getTodoList"],` in the child element. I don't know what more to do.

Comment: You are not passing the data from parent.

Comment: @Sree.Bh And how do I do that ? If I set `props: ["getTodoList"]` in parent element I will get an error saying `The computed property "getTodoList" is already defined as a prop.`

Comment: Can you please go through the link once..it is all mentioned..you can search for `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `getTodoList` to your child component like so:

`<Todo :getTodoList="getTodoList" />`

But, if you have `getTodoList` as a Vuex getter, you may as well call it directly in the child component instead, like you have the parent. If it's not being used in the parent, it's unnecessary to call it there and then pass it as a prop.

Comment: Initially, I did call the `getter` from inside the child component, but I have no idea if I can use the same store module for more than one Vue component. That's why I wanted to move the state/store functionality over to the parent component and just send it to the child.

Comment: Everything in your Vuex store is accessible to every component

Comment: That's the purpose of Vuex; to have a centralised store for all your data. This way you can avoid having to pass it from parent to child and child to sibling etc.

Comment: So you are saying that I can manipulate the `todoList` array that is inside the store module from inside child and parent components and that the array will still represent the same state ?

Comment: To manipulate it for all components you'd have to call an action within your child component which alters the data directly inside the Vuex store. Anything you do inside your child component which doesn't then get sent back to the store won't alter the original data, only for the child component.

Comment: Meaning that I will have to use `setters` inside the child component that will make commits that will call the `mutations` from the store module, right ?

Comment: So, you can use an `action` inside your child component, which then triggers a `mutation` in the store, which then mutates your `state`, which you can then call with a `getter` in any component you like. Sounds long-winded but it's super helpful when you have lots of components to manage

Comment: @Daniel_Knigths Does this mean that I can write the majority of the functionality in the module's `actions` instead of the component's `methods` ? And, basically, just call the module's `action` from the component `methods` ?

Comment: Depends what kind of methods they are. I think it's best to only have what's necessary in your store: HTTP requests and data which needs to be passed around